# Ubuntu desktop version 14.10 - how I disable the switching between the menu bar and the title bar on top of a window?

Tags: unity, gnome

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 14.10 with Unity and the Windows have switch between a title bar and the menu bar when I move the mouse to the top bar of the window? I want the menu bar permanently displayed and the annoying switching disabled.

Comment: I recall they added back this feature of Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10. No idea how to get it back though, must be a Nautulis setting somewhere with Window menu options.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree -- This is a major pain.

To clarify, this is what you see AFTER you've disabled global menus using the Settings/Appearance/Behavior "In the window's title bar" clickie.

It puts the menus in the right place, then makes actually using the menus difficult.